# Best way to close the program pressing Esc anytime the user wants?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-keyboard

Which is the best way to close a program anytime by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>?
I need to implement this thing in an important code, but my experiments didn't work.

This is the last one:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import keyboard
import sys


def stop_anytime():
    bool = True
    while bool:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
                sys.exit()
                bool = False
        except:
            break

def print_numbers():
    for n in range(150000):
        print(n)
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=stop_anytime)
    p2 = Process(target=print_numbers)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: btw, don't use `bool` as the name of a variable, it is a built-in function.

Comment: @quamrana: `bool` is the name of a built-in *`class`* — but you're right about not using it as the name of a variable.

Comment: Ok, the documentation calls it both a class and a function. I thought I'd check before commenting and I found [built-in function bool()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values)

Comment: This [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) says it's a class — although classes _are_ callable in Python…

Comment: Yes, I just said that.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keyboard` module is multithreaded, so you don't need to use the `multiprocessing` module yourself to do this. I think the cleanest way to do things would be to use the [`keyboard.hook()`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.hook) function to specify a callback function that does what's needed.

**Note:** Since this callback will be invoked from a separate `keyboard` thread, calling `sys.exit()` in it will only exit that, not the whole program/process. To accomplish that you need to call [`os._exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) instead.

```
import keyboard
import os


def exit_on_key(keyname):
    """ Create callback function that exits current process when the key with
        the given name is pressed.
    """
    def callback(event):
        if event.name == keyname:
            os._exit(1)
    return callback


def print_numbers():
    for n in range(150000):
        print(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    keyboard.hook(exit_on_key('esc'))
    print_numbers()
```

Comment: It doesn't work: it says me that exit_on_key and keyname are not defined

Comment: I can only assume you're somehow not running the code in my answer, because not only does it work for me, there's no explanation I can think of to explain the errors you're encountering.

Comment: My fault, you're completely right sorry. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

edit: this works:

```py
import keyboard
import sys

def print_numbers():
    for n in range(150000):
        print(n)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
            sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_numbers()
```

you have to join the processes like this:

```
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

or maybe that has to be done with threading only

also you maybe could do this:

```
def print_numbers():
    for n in range(150000):
        print(n)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
            sys.exit()
```

or possibly even use pygame module for the code above to register key presses

Comment: Ok, this works with that example, but I need to be able to quit anytime I want. Meaning that I have a longer function with a selenium webdriver working and I want to be able to quit even when webdriver is searching on the web. This is why I thought to use processes